# upgrade m3.large instance to c3.xlarge without rebooting or making any changes to the existing server

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon EC2 m3.large instance. I want to upgrade this instance to c3.xlarge without rebooting or making any changes to the existing server. This is our production environment, so what is the best and risk-free way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the instance type of a running instance. You need to shutdown the instance in order to change the instance type.

The best and risk free way of migration to another instance type is to setup a new instance, deploy the environment and change the elastic ip when the setup is finished.

Comment: *"you can resize EBS volumes attached to an running instance."*  When did this become possible?

Comment: Ok. Sorry. I might have been wrong about that. Deleted the sentence.

Comment: Thanks...I also have tried and found nothing...I think it's not possible